# Event syntax vs delegate syntax in c# application

Tags: c#, .net, events, syntax, delegates

I have searched about `the use of event syntax and its importance in c# code`. So I found these advantages :

1. An event cannot be directly assigned ( we don't have the risk of someone removing all previous subscriptions, as with delegate syntax
2. No outside users can raise the event

I write this snippet to more understand these points above :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace certiflibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Pub p = new Pub();
            p.OnChange += () => Console.WriteLine("First");
            p.OnChange += () => Console.WriteLine("Second");
            p.OnChange = () => Console.WriteLine("Third");
            p.Raise();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(p.OnChange.GetInvocationList().Length);
            Console.ReadKey();

            PubEvent pubevent = new PubEvent();
            pubevent.OnchangeEvent += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Event Raised: {0}",e.Name);
            pubevent.Raise();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Pub
    {
        public Action OnChange { get; set; }

        public void Raise()
        {
         if(OnChange != null)
         {
             OnChange();
         }
        }
    }

    public class PubEvent
    {

        public event EventHandler<SpecialArgs> OnchangeEvent = delegate { };

        public void Raise()
        {
            OnchangeEvent(this, new SpecialArgs("hello"));
        }
    }

    public class SpecialArgs:EventArgs
    {
        public SpecialArgs(string _name)
        {
         Name= _name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The first point is clear: I can not directly assign an event . But I don't understand the second one , even in my code I can access to the event from outside the class and raise it.

So, How can Event syntax prevent unwanted users to raise the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even in my code I can access to the event from outside the class and raise it

No, you can't.

You could call

```
p.OnChange()
```

since `OnChange` is a simple property, but you can not call

```
pubevent.OnchangeEvent()
```

since `OnchangeEvent` is an event.

The compiler would complain with

> The event 'UserQuery.PubEvent.OnchangeEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'UserQuery.PubEvent')

So, you can call `OnchangeEvent` only from inside the `PubEvent` class, and that's exactly what you do in your `Raise` method. `OnchangeEvent` can't be raised from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

You defined a method in your class that raises the event.

If this method is public anybody may call that method.

The event system prevents things like `pubevent.OnchangeEvent(...)`